# Ajax URL # isn't updating

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a little problem with my script here. For some reason, it doesn't enable the #-tags and I don't know why. I created this javascript using the help of this [tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/). (The loading of the pages works well with no problems at all.)

Could someone please look it over and tell me why it doesn't work?

```
 var default_content="";

    $(document).ready(function(){   //executed after the page has loaded

        checkURL(); //check if the URL has a reference to a page and load it

        $('ul li a').click(function (e){    //traverse through all our navigation links..

                checkURL(this.hash);    //.. and assign them a new onclick event, using their own hash as a parameter (#page1 for example)

        });

        setInterval("checkURL()",250);  //check for a change in the URL every 250 ms to detect if the history buttons have been used

    });

    var lasturl=""; //here we store the current URL hash

    function checkURL(hash)
    {
        if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;    //if no parameter is provided, use the hash value from the current address

        if(hash != lasturl) // if the hash value has changed
        {
            lasturl=hash;   //update the current hash
            loadPage(hash); // and load the new page
        }
    }

    function loadPage(url)  //the function that loads pages via AJAX
    {
        // Instead of stripping off #page, only 
        // strip off the # to use the rest of the URL
        url=url.replace('#','');

     $('#loading').css('visibility','visible'); //show the rotating gif animation

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load_page.php",
            data: 'page='+url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){

                   if(parseInt(msg)!=0) //if no errors
                {
                    $('#content').html(msg);    //load the returned html into pageContet

                }  $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');//and hide the rotating gif
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: What is actually going wrong with this? You should give more detail on what you are doing to create the error, what is actually going wrong and what you are expecting to happen. At the moment it is totally unclear whether its not loading the pages, whether its not doing ajax or something else entirely. Are you getting any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: You should really just use the hashchange event, it's been well supported since IE8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange

Comment: @nullability Thanks for the tipp and sorry to ask but could you show m2 how I have to include that? when I tried it, my page didin't load... something like hashChange is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this immensely by adding a function to listen to the `hashchange` event, like this:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    loadPage(window.location.hash);
});
```

This way you don't need to deal with timers or overriding click events on anchors.

You also don't need to keep track of `lasthash` since the `hashchange` even will only fire when the hash changes.

Comment: is it also posible to use the [BBQ-plugin] in my code?(http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) If yes could you show my how to rewrite all my code please? Thank you for your help untill now and also for the futur suport :)

Comment: The BBQ plugin does the same thing. If you want additional help, you should create a new question.