# $POST isn't updating

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-request

I'm having a problem whit my script here and I don’t understand why.
After testing a lot I understood that the main problem is the Ajax-request. Also I have been using the Ajax-request in another version of my script... Back then the changing of my content went very well... But now I wanted to enable the back-button so I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340516/ajax-url-isnt-updating/18343529?noredirect=1#comment26994531_18343529) how that would work... I got a very good answer, so I tried to do that whit the help of this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/) 
now this below is the result:
now the changing of the url works and the old-content is fading out but the new-content (from the request) isn’t updating… 
**Update**: its's like not even sending the request...
Could someone please tell me why??

Thank you in advanced

And sorry for my bad English.

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {

    var newHash = "",
        $content = $("#content"),
        $el;

    $('ul li a').click(function () {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        url=$(this).attr("href");
        if (newHash) {
            $content

            .fadeOut(200, function () {

                //                 url=url.replace('#','');

                $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible'); //show the rotating gif animation

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_page.php",
                    data: 'page' + url,
                    success: function (msg) {

                        if (parseInt(msg) != 0) //if no errors
                        {
                            $('#content').html(msg); //load the returned html into pageContet

                        }
                        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //and hide the rotating gif
                    }

                });

                $('ul li a').removeClass("current");
                $("'ul li a'[href='" + newHash + "']").addClass("current");
            });

        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['page'])) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

//  validate it as alphanumeric before reading the filesystem
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $_POST['page']) && file_exists('article/'.$page.'.html')) {
  echo file_get_contents('article/'.$page.'.html');
}
else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

**Update:** In the firebug-plugin I get this:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'ul li a[href='anmeldung']

[image: This is how my FireBug Consol looks like...] does this meens the URL was empty?

Comment: Change `data: 'page'+url,` to `data: 'page='+url,`

Comment: @adho12 Even though it's only one key/value pair, it's nice to pass an object and let jQuery handle everything. You could use `data: { page: url }`

Comment: @putvande, lan sorry, none of them did fix the problem at all... but still thank you

Comment: Where did you define `url`? And are you fading `#content` back in somewhere?

Comment: Use Firebug/web developer tool to check whether the request is going out, and whether it is returning what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $content = $("#content");



    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    }); 

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        url=newHash
        if (newHash) {
            $content

                .fadeOut(200, function() {

         url=url.replace('#','');

 $('#loading').css('visibility','visible'); //show the rotating gif animation

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        success: function(msg){

               if(parseInt(msg)!=0) //if no errors
            {
                 $content.fadeIn(200, function() {
            $('#content').html(msg);}); //load the returned html into pageContet

            }  $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');//and hide the rotating gif
        }

    });

                        $('ul li a').removeClass("current");
                        $('ul li a[href="' + newHash + '"]').addClass('current');
                    });

        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Ahhh I found the Error
the problem was that I set url to late...
Thanks every person - robot who looked and helped me solve this ^^

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$("'ul li a'[href='" + newHash + "']").addClass("current");
```

Into this one:

```
$('ul li a[href="' + newHash + '"]').addClass('current');
```

At least *that's* the syntax error FireBug is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data to your PHP script in the wrong way.
You should be sending it as `key=value`, you are sending it like `keyvalue`, so your PHP script never gets the `page` variable.

So change your script from

```
data: 'page'+url,
```

to

```
data: 'page='+url,
//         ^
```

Comment: sorry, that did not fix the problem at all... but still thank you